# What is the purpose of instrumentation console

Tags: lightning, summer-16

What is the purpose of instrumentation console introduced in Summer'16 lightning view and how can this be used in development process ? There is no mention of this in the Summer'16 release notes also.

Answer (score 2):

Like we have console, network and other tools in developer tools of a browser where they logs information associated with a web page: network requests, JavaScript, CSS, security errors and warnings. Likewise, Salesforce has created Instrumentation console where we see the interactions- upon clicking anywhere on the page. One can see the **Time since loaded, Session start time, Previous Page URL, Sequence**, etc.

You can record your interactions and play them again to see the stats, you can download the JSON format of the interaction from right bottom corner icon, you can also load interaction files.
And in the **View Waterfall** option you can see stats for the transaction and when you play the recorded interaction you can see in different views as chosen in **I want to ...** dropdown.

Hope this helps to give an idea what is it for.

Comment: Thanks for your response, that was helpful. Is there any salesforce documentation on how to leverage this tool and directions to use

Comment: Lightning itself is in development. So, don't expect any documentation soon. :)